# Autocomplete - Modifying the selected and set item

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete as below:

```
$('#' + id).autocomplete({
                minLength: minLength,
                source: function (d, cb) {
                 ...

                }

               // select event of ocr number autocomplete
                select: function (evt, item) {
                ...
                // set ocr number
                    var inputValue = item.item.value; //0033-ABCDEF
                    var tempArr = inputValue.split('-'); 
                    inputValue = tempArr[0]; // 0033
               ...

              }
        });
```

Input : 0033
List comes up for autocomplete - 0033-ABCDEF(First result)

Vaue setting by autocomplete when i select **0033-ABCDEF** but i need it to **0033**

I know this is the default property for autocomplete but need to override it on select() to give a splitted result.

Thanks in advance!!!

--
GOK

Comment: To be honest , I didn't understand your case. Can you please rephrase your question or add an example please?

Comment: Did it make sense or ask me specific questions for clarification...

Comment: So are you saying the entire list behind it should display for example 0033 and that should mean 0033-ABCDEF, or are you saying that if they typed 0033, the list should show 0033, but if they kept typing like 0033-AB it should now show 0033-AB?

It might help to include the data being loaded into this in your question.

Comment: Nope... dont go for loading of list.. the list should load as i have shown(if i type 0033 - it comes with lost starting 0033-ABCD). My question is i want to set it as 0033(splitted value before '-') but autocomplete has default property that it will set the same value what is selected in the list i.e., 0033-ABCD but i want to split and set only 0033. Will it be possible?

Comment: was i clear with my query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#' + id)
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: minLength, 
        source: function(d, cb) {
            ...
        }
        // select event of ocr number autocomplete
        select: function(evt, item) {
            // set ocr number
            var inputValue = item.item.value; //0033-ABCDEF
            var tempArr = inputValue.split('-');
            inputValue = tempArr[0]; // 0033

            $(this).val(inputValue); // Sets the value manually in the text field

            return false; // Prevent default behaviour
        }
    });
```

Comment: is this the best way around... I thought of some method of autocomplete which we can override to achieve this...

Comment: What is the problem with it? Now if you have control over the data source you can define the `label` and the `value` like described here http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source. Your source would look like `source: [ { label: "0033-ABCDEF", value: "0033" }, ... ]`